# Comparing two range and copying

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two Range and copy data based on IF and AND condition, but AND condition is not working as a result data is being copied only based on IF condition. Please suggest what change should I make in code. Below is Code which I am currently using:

```
Sub Copy3()

    Dim mCell As Range
    Dim yRange As Range
    Dim mRange As Range
    Dim RRange As Range

    Set mRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("DB2:DB17")
     Set yRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("CZ2:CZ17")
     Set RRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("CY2:CY17")
    Set target = mRange.Offset(columnoffset:=-3)

    Dim P As Long, Q As Long, t As Long
    For P = 1 To mRange.Cells.Count
    For Q = 1 To RRange.Cells.Count
    For t = 1 To yRange.Cells.Count

        If mRange.Cells(P).Value <> "" And RRange.Cells(Q).Value <> yRange.Cells(t).Value Then
           mRange.Cells(P).Copy target.Cells(P)
        End If

    Next
    Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The condition that you have in your code is the condition that you have in your code. Apparently, it isn't the same as the condition that you want to have, but since you have given us no information about what that would be, I don't see how this question can be answered.

Comment: The condition appears to be set correctly, unless you proide some information on what it is supposed to do, no one can fix this for you.

Comment: Specifically ythe first time through your loops you check if DB2 is not null, then compare CY2 against every cell CZ2 to CZ17 and if any of them don't match you then copy DB2 into CY2. The next time round you check if DB2 is not null then compare CY3 against CZ2 to CZ17 etc. In total you do 4913 comparisons. I don't think that's what you intend to do

Comment: the target variable is not defined - for sure this is a range but which one. You could also define a whole range covering all the columns including the result column and sweep the whole set row by row with something like **For each row in wholeRange.rows** then manage the offset for each column with something like  **row.offset(0,1).Resize(1,1)** that would point to  **mRange.Cells(P)**

Comment: @HarassedDad i am trying to compare only CY2 with CZ2, CY3 with CZ3 and goes on and if CY2 is not equals to CZ2 then copy DB2

Comment: @JohnColeman i am trying to compare only CY2 with CZ2, CY3 with CZ3 and goes on and if CY2 is not equals to CZ2 then copy DB2

Comment: Then you need to lose three of your loops

Answer (score 0):

you can try this (the sheet name and ranges must be changed to reflect the structure of your data). I made the assumption that target points to column A. The address of the cells is traced to make it easier to check if this is in deed what you expect the code to do.

```
Dim wholeRange As Range
Set wholeRange = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A2:D17")

If (Not wholeRange Is Nothing) Then
    Dim row As Range, rP As Range, rQ As Range, rR As Range, rT As Range
    For Each row In wholeRange.Rows
        Set rP = row.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1)
        Set rR = row.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 1)
        Set rQ = row.Offset(0, 3).Resize(1, 1)
        Set rT = row.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 1)
        Debug.Print "P:" + rP.Address + " R:" + rR.Address + " Q:" + rQ.Address + " T:" + rT.Address
        If (rP.Cells(1, 1).Value <> "") And (rQ.Cells(1, 1).Value <> rT.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
           rP.Cells(1, 1).Value = rT.Cells(1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next row
Else
    Debug.Print "wholeRange range is not defined"
End If
```